# Behavioural logic sequential, code cannot work?

Tags: vhdl

Basically I have the following code in my module. I want to change a number to it's 2's complement negative.

Eg. 100 becomes -100, and -200 becomes 200.

A shortcut I found is to read from the LSB until you reach a '1', then flip all the bits after it. I'm trying a implement a 32 bit converter using the least performance tradeoff (I heard num <= not(num) + 1 is quite resource heavy)

```
                flipBit <= '0'; -- reset the flip bit
                FOR i IN 0 TO 31 LOOP
                    IF flipBit = '1' THEN
                        tempSubtract(i) <= not Operand2(i);
                    ELSE
                        tempSubtract(i) <= Operand2(i);
                    END IF;
                    IF Operand2(i) = '1' THEN
                        flipBit <= '1';
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
```

However, all it does it to NOT the entire thing. Also, when I do num <= not(num)+1, the slow way, it gives me gibberish numbers too.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You should make flipBit a variable and not a signal so it does get updated in the for loop and not at the end of your process.

Comment: It works. It was very careless of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something the synthesis tool can probably do better than you, so I would recommend to simply use `z <= -a;`, where `a` and `z` are of type `signed`.

This will cause synthesis to optimize the negation for your target architecture, no matter what it is. For example, calculating not + 1 in an FPGA is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do: signal <= signal * -1 and the tools would synthesize it for you.  That might not be the most efficient though.  I don't think it would take up THAT much logic though.  If you really need a more efficient solution you can do this:

Is there any reason you need to do this conversion you show above in 1 clock cycle?  If you took 32 clocks to do it it would be easier and probably less resources.  I would recommend that you remove your FOR loop, as it is causing most of the problems you are having.